# Проблема в коде удаления из строки всех слова начинающиеся на гласную букву

Tags: c++, c

Есть код, удаляет из строки все слова, начинающиеся на гласную букву. Не пойму почему при удалении удаляет и первую букву строки.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[] = "word apple";
    char symbols[13] = "AaEeIiOoUuYy";
    int counter(0), i(0);

    while (str[i])
    {
        if (i == 0 || str[i - 1] == ' ')
        {
            for (int j(0); symbols[j]; j++)
            {
                if (str[i] == symbols[j])
                {
                    while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0')
                        str[i++];
                }
            }

            str[counter] = str[i++];
        }
        else
            str[counter++] = str[i++];
    }

    str[counter - 1] = '\0';
    cout << str;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) У вас ошибка уже на первой же итерации цикла: `if(i == 0 || str[i-1] == ' '){`. 2) Посмотрите на `strchr()`, `memmove()` etc, велосипеды не нужны. 3) `str[i++];` - этот код что делает? 4) Научитесь пользоваться отладчиком

Comment: @PinkTux в чем ошибка здесь `if(i == 0 || str[i-1] == ' ')` ?

Comment: Стоп, тут нет ошибки :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, похоже, просто забыли `++` при `counter` в ветке `i==0`

```
str[counter] = str[i++];
```

Вот и происходит перезапись.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, главная ошибка в этом коде - попытка сделать всё сразу и применение велосипедов для каждой мелкой операции. Вместо того, чтобы разбить задачу на блоки, отладить каждый из них, и собрать в готовое решение. В результате получается каша из кода, которую сложно и воспринимать, и отлаживать.

Как вариант. Возможно, не самый эффективный, но куда более понятный и поддающийся наглядной отладке даже глазами:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
static inline int is_vowel( char c )
{
    static char vowels[] = "AaEeIiOoUuYy";
    return strchr( vowels, c ) != NULL;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
static char *compress( char *str )
{
    char *s = str;

    while( *s ) {
        /* пропускаем пробелы: */
        while( *s && isspace( *s ) ) s++;
        if( !*s ) break;

        if( is_vowel( *s ) ) {
            /*
             * 1. ищем конец слова
             * 2. пропускаем концевые пробелы
             * 3. переносим остаток строки
             */
            char *word_end = s;
            while( *word_end && !isspace( *word_end ) ) word_end++;
            while( *word_end && isspace( *word_end ) ) word_end++;
            memmove( s, word_end, strlen( word_end )+1 );
        }
        else {
            /* не гласная - пропускаем слово: */
            while( *s && !isspace( *s ) ) s++;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
int main()
{
    char str[] = "banana apple potato onion deadbeef";

    printf( "Before : '%s'\n", str );
    printf( "After  : '%s'\n", compress( str ) );

    return !*str;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```